# jQuery: append next to last?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, append

Here's my HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Then I append a new item with this: `$('ol').append('<li>New item</li>');`

But, what I want to do, is append that new before the last item. So in this example, the new list item would be placed between the second and third. The number of items in the list could be as few as 2 or as many as hundreds, but it should always insert before the next to last item.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For that, you have to select the last list item and then tell jQuery to add the new one before the one selected:

```
$('ol li:last').before('<li>New item</li>');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
$('ol li:last').before('<li>New item</li>');
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/q9qSy/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ol').last().prev().append('<li>New item</li>');
```

should work I believe.

Or indeed, what the person above & below me said looks a bit neater :)

Comment: Figured, after I saw the other submissions :) I'm used to being very explicit while coding.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this when the last list item had a special class.  I needed to do this:

```
<ul id="my_ul">
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li class="last_class">Always Last</li>
</ul>

$('#my_ul li.last_class').before('<li>New Item</li>');
```